Generation of presigned urls in golang from minio
self taught go programmer here. Its my first time trying to integrate minio in my project. Somehow i've managed to handle the savind and deleting files from minio bucket and it even has some nice structure. But i'm having problem generating presigned urls for my images that have to be loaded to the template. Im running my project along with db and minio on docker containers this way:
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15
    container_name: db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: AShelter
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - app_network

  app:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: golang_app
    environment:
      DB_USER: postgres
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      DB_NAME: AShelter
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_PORT: 5432
      MINIO_ENDPOINT: minio:9000
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: minioadmin
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: minioadmin
      MINIO_BUCKET_NAME: animal-shelter-media
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - minio
    entrypoint: [ "./wait-for-it.sh", "minio:9000", "--", "/app/main" ]
    networks:
      - app_network

  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    container_name: minio
    command: server --console-address ":9001" /data
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: minioadmin
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: minioadmin
      MINIO_BROWSER: "on"
      MINIO_CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN: "*"
    ports:
      - "9000:9000" # API MinIO
      - "9001:9001" # Web UI MinIO
    volumes:
      - minio_data:/data
    networks:
      - app_network

volumes:
  db_data:
  minio_data:

networks:
  app_network:
    name: shelter_network


The url generation looks to be working fine except i get url that are starting like :
http://minio:9000/animal-shelter-media/profile_images/user/elzarchik4816/profile_images/1733218800_181-182_GEmW.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=minioadmin%2F20241203%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20241203T114908Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=4af793e69273e3f5dec60cfe3d26b22aa4b741595e7ef0b451e3cbfa2bb6ce61
The problem is here http://minio:9000/. I suppose because the minio runs on container, it also generates links relaitve to container, but it cant be accessed on my browser.
Here is how i try to generate url in my minio.go file:
package storage

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/minio/minio-go/v7"
    "github.com/minio/minio-go/v7/pkg/credentials"
)

type MinioClient struct {
    Client *minio.Client
    Bucket string
}

// NewMinioClient creates client for MinIO
func NewMinioClient() (*MinioClient, error) {
    // Getting env variables
    endpoint := os.Getenv("MINIO_ENDPOINT")
    accessKey := os.Getenv("MINIO_ACCESS_KEY")
    secretKey := os.Getenv("MINIO_SECRET_KEY")
    bucketName := os.Getenv("MINIO_BUCKET_NAME")

    client, err := minio.New(endpoint, &minio.Options{
        Creds:  credentials.NewStaticV4(accessKey, secretKey, ""),
        Secure: false,
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error initializing MinIO client: %w", err)
    }

    
    ctx := context.Background()
    exists, err := client.BucketExists(ctx, bucketName)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to check if bucket exists: %w", err)
    }

    
    if !exists {
        err := client.MakeBucket(ctx, bucketName, minio.MakeBucketOptions{})
        if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to create bucket: %w", err)
        }
        log.Printf("Bucket %s created", bucketName)
    } else {
        log.Printf("Bucket %s already exists", bucketName)
    }

    return &MinioClient{
        Client: client,
        Bucket: bucketName,
    }, nil
}

// UploadFile handles uploading to minio bucket
func (m *MinioClient) UploadFile(ctx context.Context, objectName, filePath, contentType string) (string, error) {
    info, err := m.Client.FPutObject(ctx, m.Bucket, objectName, filePath, minio.PutObjectOptions{
        ContentType: contentType,
    })
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("error uploading file to MinIO: %w", err)
    }

    log.Printf("Successfully uploaded %s of size %d\n", info.Key, info.Size)
    return fmt.Sprintf("/%s/%s", m.Bucket, objectName), nil
}

func (m *MinioClient) GeneratePresignedURL(objectName string, expires time.Duration) (string, error) {
    
    ctx := context.Background()

    
    presignedURL, err := m.Client.PresignedGetObject(ctx, m.Bucket, objectName, expires, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("failed to generate presigned URL: %w", err)
    }

    
    return presignedURL.String(), nil
}


and this is where i call the function:
// ShowProfile handles rendering the profile of the current user
func ShowProfile(db *gorm.DB, minioClient *storage.MinioClient, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    
    sessionCookie, err := r.Cookie("session")
    if err != nil || sessionCookie.Value == "" {
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/login", http.StatusSeeOther)
        return
    }

    var session models.Session
    if err := db.Where("session_id = ?", sessionCookie.Value).First(&session).Error; err != nil {
        if errors.Is(err, gorm.ErrRecordNotFound) {
            http.Error(w, "Session not found", http.StatusUnauthorized)
        } else {
            log.Println("Database error:", err)
            http.Error(w, "Internal server error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }
        return
    }

    if session.ExpiresAt != nil && session.ExpiresAt.Before(time.Now()) {
        http.Error(w, "Session expired", http.StatusUnauthorized)
        return
    }

    var user models.User
    if err := db.Preload("Role").First(&user, session.UserID).Error; err != nil {
        if errors.Is(err, gorm.ErrRecordNotFound) {
            http.Error(w, "User not found", http.StatusNotFound)
        } else {
            log.Println("Database error:", err)
            http.Error(w, "Internal server error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }
        return
    }

    var userDetail models.UserDetail
    if err := db.First(&userDetail, "user_id = ?", user.ID).Error; err != nil {
        if errors.Is(err, gorm.ErrRecordNotFound) {
            log.Println("User details not found for user ID:", user.ID)
        } else {
            log.Println("Database error:", err)
            http.Error(w, "Internal server error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
    }

    var userImage models.UserImage
    if err := db.First(&userImage, "user_id = ?", user.ID).Error; err != nil {
        if errors.Is(err, gorm.ErrRecordNotFound) {
            log.Println("User images not found for user ID:", user.ID)
        } else {
            log.Println("Database error:", err)
            http.Error(w, "Internal server error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
    }

    var userPrivacy models.UserPrivacy
    if err := db.First(&userPrivacy, "user_id = ?", user.ID).Error; err != nil {
        if errors.Is(err, gorm.ErrRecordNotFound) {
            log.Println("User privacy settings not found for user ID:", user.ID)
        } else {
            log.Println("Database error:", err)
            http.Error(w, "Internal server error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
    }

    profileImageURL, err := minioClient.GeneratePresignedURL("profile_images/"+userImage.ProfileImage, time.Hour*24)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error generating profile image URL:", err)
        http.Error(w, "Internal server error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    backgroundImageURL, err := minioClient.GeneratePresignedURL("background_images/"+userImage.ProfileBgImage, time.Hour*24)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error generating background image URL:", err)
        http.Error(w, "Internal server error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    profileData := struct {
        User               models.User
        UserDetail         models.UserDetail
        UserPrivacy        models.UserPrivacy
        ProfileImageURL    string
        BackgroundImageURL string
    }{
        User:               user,
        UserDetail:         userDetail,
        UserPrivacy:        userPrivacy,
        ProfileImageURL:    profileImageURL,
        BackgroundImageURL: backgroundImageURL,
    }

    err = profileTemplate.Execute(w, profileData)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Template rendering error:", err)
        http.Error(w, "Error rendering profile", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}

I've tried using additional environment variables with value localhost:9000, so i could just manually change string  in generated url from minio:9000 to localhost:9000, but  i get the errorr of the unmatched singnature. Of course i get that this is really stupid try to solve this. But i literally have no idea how to properly generate links so it could be accessed outside of the minio container, from  my browser at least

This answer suggests a combination of configuration options that would create a presigned URL accessible from outside of Docker, while using the actual Docker network to directly connect to MinIO.  Does that setup help?  (It's a .NET answer, but the configuration options might work in Go too.)

Thanks, i'll try to follow the guide and let you know if i had any progress
